# programmatically highlight text in form smartgwt

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, smartgwt

I've got a method:

```
public void generateLink() {
        String url = com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.Location.getHref();
        String[] url2 = url.split("&xmx");
        url = url2[0];
        float xmax = extent.getXMax();
        float xmin = extent.getXMin();
        float ymax = extent.getYMax();
        float ymin = extent.getYMin();
        int wkid2 = this.wkid;
        url = url + "&xmx="+xmax+"&xmn="+xmin+"&ymx="+ ymax+"&ymn="+ymin+"&wkid=" + wkid2;      
        textItem_link_do_mapy.setValue(url);
        textItem_link_do_mapy.setSelectOnFocus(true);
        textItem_link_do_mapy.focusInItem();

    }
```

I wanna highlight textitem component after putting a text to it. How could I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the style of the TextItem, and set the css properties it in your css sheet

```
textItem_link_do_mapy.setTextBoxStyle("highlight");

.highlight {
  background-color: rgb(255,255,0)
}
```